# Get array values in different scene Javafx

Tags: java, arrays, generics, javafx

I'm tryin to pass values to a generic array in one scene and display values in another. I've tested and the code below prints out the array values on the same scene that I pass the parameters. The problem is when I switch scenes and print the values I get an error message saying it doesn' exist even if it's the same controller.

Error when I try to get array values from new scene.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Shop.getItems(Shop.java:50)
    ... 58 more
```

Class..

```
public class Shop implements Initializable {
    @FXML private TextField name;
    @FXML private TextField quantity;
    @FXML private TextArea list;

    MyArrayList<Item> array = new MyArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    @FXML
    private void addItem() {

        int q = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText());
        String n = name.getText();

        Item item = new Item(n,q);

        array.add(item);

        //Print out values added above
        System.out.println(array.getItem(0).name);
        System.out.println(array.getItem(0).quantity);

    }

    @FXML
    public void getItems() {
        list.setText(array.getItem(0).name);
    }

    @FXML
    private void getCart(ActionEvent ae) throws IOException {
        Node node = (Node)ae.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage)node.getScene().getWindow();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("cart.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
    }

    @FXML
    private void getShop (ActionEvent ae) throws IOException {
        Node node = (Node)ae.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage)node.getScene().getWindow();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("shop.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);

    }
}
```

Comment: that's not an array, that's a `List`, arrays don't support `add` :)

Comment: the NPE comes from `getItems()`, because no NPE is thrown at `array.add(item)` I believe it's `list` variable that's null, can you show us the definition of this `list` variable and the code in which you switch scenes ?

Comment: Yes, the generic class array deletes all indexes when I change the scene. The add function works because I can print out values from the array when I add values, but only in the same scene. I have updated with the code above.

Comment: thanks, could you also show us the full stacktrace of the exception, I notice `Caused By` but where is the referred ?

Comment: my suspection is that either `shop.fxml` doesn't have the `list` TextArea(thus it's `null`) or 'cart.fxml' doesn't have it

Comment: I just double checked and the cart.fxml have the list Textarea. It's when I change the scene with getCart() that the array gets empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass object from one scene to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508182/pass-object-from-one-scene-to-another)

Comment: see the duplicate , it's the same problem as yours

Comment: I assume `getItems()` is invoked as an event handler for some control defined in an FXML file. Can you [edit] the question to include that FXML file?

Comment: I used a Singelton to solve the problem.